# why is box not aligned properly?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="productcontainer">
<div class="product"><img src="products/p1.jpg" height="75" /><br />Item 1</div>
<div class="product"><img src="products/p1.jpg" height="75" /><br />Item 2</div>
<div class="product"><img src="products/p1.jpg" height="75" /><br />Item 3<br />Test</div>
<div class="product"><img src="products/p1.jpg" height="75" /><br />Item 4</div>
<div class="product"><img src="products/p1.jpg" height="75" /><br />Item 5</div>
</div>

.productcontainer { width: 320px }
.product { width: 100px; height: 100px; display: inline-block; border: solid 1px #000000 }
```

Why is Item 3 not aligned at the top?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align: top` to `.product`.

For further information, see:

- http://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-block.html
- http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Answer (score 2):

Use `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block`
Here's how it looks like with `float:left`: http://jsfiddle.net/techappetite/H7LfR/